# Format 1800 date in SQL Server & Oracle

Tags: sql, oracle, sql-server-2008

I have the following date in our SQL Server 2008 database: `06-24-1881 00:00:00:000` as a `DOB` and it's stored as `datetime`.

I need to copy this data into our Oracle 11g database and from my understanding Oracle does not accept milliseconds into a `Datetime` column. For my data after 1900 I converted the data to `smalldatetime` and it worked but for this piece of data, it won't convert to `smalldatetime` since it doesn't allow for dates prior to 1/1/1900.

How do I get many rows of data into my Oracle database?

I tried this:

```
left(DOB, 19) as DOB
```

but that rendered the data as "Jun 24 1881 12:00AM", so I tried inserting with:

```
to_date('Jun 24 1881 12:00AM', 'MON-DD-YYYY HH:MI:SSAM')
```

and that didn't work either. I am stuck and need help.

Comment: What do you mean by "rendered the date as"? If you were able to "transfer" the date into Oracle as a datetime, its "rendering" via your session NLS_date_format is irrelevant, the internal (stored) datetime format in Oracle is unique, it contains the seconds as well, and no AM suffix; those are only added when the date is displayed.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`Jun 24 1881 12:00AM` matches the Oracle format string `MON DD YYYY HH12:MIAM`. Your format mask has an added seconds `:SS` mask that Oracle is trying to match but not finding in the input so will throw an `ORA-01861: literal does not match format string` exception.

So, if the output from SQL Server is in that format then in Oracle you should be able to do:

```
TO_DATE( 'Jun 24 1881 12:00AM', 'MON DD YYYY HH12:MIAM' )
```

Answer (score 0):

`CONVERT(VARCHAR(20),@Date,101)` will give you 06/24/1881 I am looking for code now.

```
REPLACE(CONVERT(VARCHAR(200),@Date,101),'/','-') + ' 00:00:00:000'
```

Weird I tried a bunch of the century codes with CONVERT and it worked for 101 and some others but the 113 you want failed but because you don't have minutes, hours, seconds etc. you can just take the the 101 format and manipulate the string to what you want.

```
    DECLARE @Date DATE = '06-24-1881 00:00:00:000'

    SELECT @Date
        ,FORMAT(@Date, 'MM-dd-yyyy HH:mm:ss')
,REPLACE(CONVERT(VARCHAR(200),@Date,101),'/','-') + ' 00:00:00:000'
```

Note the `FORMAT(@Date, 'MM-dd-yyyy HH:mm:ss')` is SQL 2012 or newer and works well.